# No option for "Add Client Side Library" on Visual Studio Mac 2019

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2, visual-studio-mac

Can't see any option to add client side library on Visual Studio for Mac 2019 (Version 8.3.3).

Seems to be supported as I seen a few tutorials on a Mac for it but can't seem to find the option myself.

Answer (score 8):

You have to run the following command to install *libman* on your macOS:

```
dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli
```

After running the above command try:

```
libman --version
```

If you get the error ***Command not found: libman***

Then also run the following command:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/username/.dotnet/tools"
```

where *username* would be your macOS user.

Comment: The export helped. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work with VS 2022

Answer (score 7):

Go to Menu Visual Studio, Extensions, Gallery, add library manager, restart Visual studio, and in the Add client-said Library solution, that's it

Comment: Thank you, this is working for me on:

Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac
Version 17.6.7 (build 417)

Answer (score 4):

There is a [separate Library Manager extension](https://lastexitcode.com/blog/2019/07/13/LibManSupportInVisualStudioMac8-1/) you can install which adds support for LibMan in Visual Studio for Mac.

Otherwise you can install the [libman global tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-cli) and use the command line.

```
dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli
```

Comment: Thanks it worked adding the Libman extension, following the first link that you have provided.